# Why did the chinese murderess not kill Johnny in the golf camp?

Tags: plot-explanation, johnny-english-reborn

In Johnny English Reborn, when he was sent to chase Vortex men, a Chinese old woman was sent to kill him. She disguised as a female janitor with a creepy vacuum cleaner, which was actually an also disguised weapon.

She wanted to kill him many times in the movie, even at the end of the movie when Vortex did not exist anymore. But when they were looking for Karlenko, the second Vortex man (the Russian guy) in the golf camp, he gave an order to one of his thugs -in Russian- to kill Johnny and Tucker.

The Chinese woman had Johnny in sight and was also -in the distance, but ready, with her sniper- about to kill Johnny, but then she noticed Karlenko and the thug taking his gun to kill Johnny, and aimed karlenko and shot, not killing Johnny.

Is there a reason for the woman to not kill Johnny in that moment but kill Karlenko?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She wasn't sent to kill Johnny (looking at him throw the sniper was just for a dramatic reason), **she was sent to kill the second Vortex guy before he talks** and she simply accomplished her mission. Notice that Johnny is just an agent, if he died another will be send (actually another agent -Tucker- was already there).

Also the same thing happened when she killed the first Vortex guy, she could've aimed at Johnny but didn't simply because he's not as important as the two Vortex guys who have a lot of information about the origination and about the third member.